# Azure Delete My configuration Of My Cloud Service, Why?

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service in Azure (WCF).

My Web App' (MVC) is consuming the cloud service.

Yesterday I used my Web App' and I got errors in consuming the cloud service.
I connected to the machine hosting my cloud service to see what the problem there, and to my surprise  all my customization of the machine ( I installed software, created directory and etc) all gone.

I double checked that I'm accessing the machine with the right profile (account setup on the machine), its was the right profile.

Any idea why Azure deleted my configuration on the machine ? my instance was not deleted only the configuration on it.

Weird stuff happens on Azure :)

Comment: Did you make changes by connecting to your application instances using RDP?

Comment: No, I configure all RDF, endpoint, user and etc trough the Visual Studio 2013 -> "ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg" I didn't done anything except it.

Comment: What "configuration" are you referring to? Did you do the configuration by RDPing into the machine?

Comment: Yes.
And the "configuration I referring is : creates directory, install softwares and etc.
@daronyondem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you RDP to the instance of your cloud service, created some folders and installed some applications, it will be lost some days in the future. The virtual machine cloud service was located is NOT persistent. All your customization would be lost if the VM was migrated to another rack when azure found some hardware failure or just defrag the VM resource.

You should use Startup Task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx).
If you need complex environment settings, your'd better check Azure Virtual Machine rather than Cloud Service.

HTH,

Comment: Shaun Do you have any Idea how can I deploy Worker role to VM ? 
I only see documentation about deploy to cloud service.

Comment: Worker role is a feature inside cloud service, not for VM. You can do anything you like in your VM. In this case you can install your own windows service running in background. Worker role in this case is not necessary I think.